# How to fix 'Instance failure.' up 'Update-Database'

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations

I am setting up very basic code-first approach database context for my application. I've MVC (UI), and Class library (EntityFramework) projects under my solution. On `Update-Database` getting error `Instance failure.`

// Migration configuration

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<UrfPractice.EntityFramework.UrfPracticeDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

// Database context

```
public class UrfPracticeDbContext : DbContext
{
    static UrfPracticeDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UrfPracticeDbContext>(null);
    }
    public UrfPracticeDbContext() : base("name=DefaultConnectionString")
    {
    Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    public DbSet<Entities.Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

// Customer migration

```
public partial class Customer : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
        "dbo.tblCustomers",
        c => new {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            CustomerId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            Fullname = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256)
        }).PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
    }
    public override void Down()
    { DropTable("dbo.tblCustomers"); }
}
```

// Entity class

```
[Table("tblCustomers")] public class Customer {
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
}
```

Screenshot=> https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47334134/53000129-b4582800-3438-11e9-9d17-4f1903c5d623.png
[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the context project selected in the console, then explicitly provide your startup project with connect string: `update-database -StartupProjectName MVCProjectName`

Comment: same error. `Instance failure.`

Comment: I don't know why but when I changed the data source from .\\sql2014 to .\sql2014 it works :S Thanks for your help...